# JMeter graph interpretation

Tags: jmeter, test-design, load-testing, performance, test-strategy

I'm very new at `JMeter` and am trying to get an idea of how to interpret the graphs below.

The test I performed used 1 `thread group` with 600 users ramped up ever 5 seconds.  What concerns me is the `Average Response Time` graph is flat.

Does this mean the site being tested died early on or does it mean the site is so efficient it handled all the requests without a problem?

Also, is 600 user count with 5-second ramp-up the best way to try to put a load on the site?

[image: LoadGraphs]

[image]

Comment: How many users did you start with: 600 or something else?  How many users did you add per 5 seconds?  How many transactions did you attempt per user per 5 seconds?

Comment: Maybe the close voters could explain why they think this is off-topic for sqa.

Answer (score 2):

If the site had died, your transaction rate would be zero.  The graph shows  about two successful transactions per second.